Pre-commit hooks: Executable <hook_name> not found
I try to use pre-commit on VSCode.
I installed ruff, black, mypy and flake8 using poetry.
Pre-commit-config.yaml
default_language_version:
    python: python3.10

repos:
  - repo: local

    hooks:

      - id: ruff
        name: ruff
        entry: ruff
        language: python
        types: [python]
        args: [
          --fix,
          --config=app/pyproject.toml
        ]

      - id: black
        name: black
        entry: black
        language: python
        types: [python]
        args: [
          --config=app/pyproject.toml
        ]

      - id: mypy
        name: mypy
        entry: mypy
        language: python
        types: [python]
        args: [
          --ignore-missing-imports,
          --check-untyped-defs,
          --no-implicit-optional,
          --config-file=app/pyproject.toml
        ]

      - id: flake8
        name: flake8
        entry: flake8
        language: python
        types: [ python ]
        args: [
          --config=./app/.flake8
        ]

I installed pre-commit:
pre-commit install
> pre-commit installed at .git/hooks/pre-commit

.git/hooks/pre-commit
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# File generated by pre-commit: https://pre-commit.com
# ID: 138fd403232d2ddd5efb44317e38bf03

# start templated
INSTALL_PYTHON=/Users/serg/CODING/__samolet__/lk/.venv/bin/python
ARGS=(hook-impl --config=.pre-commit-config.yaml --hook-type=pre-commit)
# end templated

HERE="$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd)"
ARGS+=(--hook-dir "$HERE" -- "$@")

if [ -x "$INSTALL_PYTHON" ]; then
    exec "$INSTALL_PYTHON" -mpre_commit "${ARGS[@]}"
elif command -v pre-commit > /dev/null; then
    exec pre-commit "${ARGS[@]}"
else
    echo '`pre-commit` not found.  Did you forget to activate your virtualenv?' 1>&2
    exit 1
fi

After that I try to commit my code and get such error:
> git -c user.useConfigOnly=true commit --quiet --allow-empty-message --file -
ruff.....................................................................Failed
- hook id: ruff
- exit code: 1

Executable `ruff` not found

black....................................................................Failed
- hook id: black
- exit code: 1

Executable `black` not found

mypy.....................................................................Failed
- hook id: mypy
- exit code: 1

Executable `mypy` not found

flake8...................................................................Failed
- hook id: flake8
- exit code: 1

Executable `flake8` not found

I found a similar issue on GitHub: Pre-commit hooks executables not found. But it didn't help me.
I tried:

pre-commit uninstall && pre-commit install;
pre-commit clean && pre-commit install-hooks.

But unsuccessfully.
Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Have you installed the requested binaries - ruff, black, mypy, and flake8?

Does this answer your question? Understanding how to configure pre-commit with repo: local

Is there a reason you need to use custom local hooks instead of the standard hooks for those tools?

I doubt that this is an ideal solution, but in my case, installing linters globally helped.
I use VSCode and make commits using the Source Control.
For some reason it does not recognise (unlike the terminal) the virtual environment of the project.
After installing the linters globally, the pre-commit works as it should.

you've written custom repo: local hooks (which are the escape hatch for the framework) and not configured them properly
if you use the supported repository format this would have worked without problem but you've bypassed the framework and are now reaping the consequences :)
even fixing the installation (you'd need to add additional_dependencies: [...] to ensure things are installed) you also have a fork bomb because you haven't copied the configuration properly
tl;dr: use the upstream repos and not repo: local / language: system unless you know what you're doing (and even then you're doing your contributors a disservice by requiring manual setup outside the framework)

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit
